# Is there a word for identifying shapes in other objects (i.e., clouds)

Tags: terminology

I"m looking for a word that describes the process or act of identifying a shape, symbol, or whatever from another shape.

For instance, if you look at clouds, sometimes you see an animal, or shape.  In TV, there was an episode where a person saw a divine image on a grilled cheese (i.e., [grilled cheesus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grilled_Cheesus)).  Johnny Carson famously brought on a woman who had various shaped potato chips (of which he acted like he ate one, much to the shock and horror of the poor woman).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Pareidolia:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pareidolia)** The tendency to interpret a vague stimulus as something known to the observer, such as interpreting marks on Mars as canals, seeing shapes in clouds, or hearing hidden messages in music.